# How to extract Text Before and After NSRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsrange

I am applying a search in a large content.Using NSRange to achieve this.

```
range = [textToSearch rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

and then I am checking the presence of String like this:

```
if(range.location != NSNotFound){
   //String found
 }
```

Now I have only the Range for specified string. I want to display my search result as:

Suppose My Content is this:

> I am a movie fanatic. When friends want to know what picture won the Oscar in 1980 or who played the police chief in Jaws, they ask me. My friends, though, have stopped asking me if I want to go out to the movies.

Now I have made a search for "Stopped"

Now I want to display my search as:

Result:

My friends, though, have **stopped** asking me if I want to

I want some word before and after searched result. I don't know how to acheive this.

Comment: Adjust the location by subtracting the number of characters you'd like to include.  Make sure to do a MAX(0, newLocation) to avoid going negative.  Do the same for length, taking care not to go past the end of the string.

Comment: How to achieve this ?

Comment: And next time, show what you've tried.  SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @Avi I have written the code what I have tried... and I am not able to proceed that's why I asked..If you feel I am wanting for a service then keep out of it

Comment: So show the code you wrote and explain why it doesn't work, if you can.  The answer is 4 lines of code, two of which are simple math expressions.

Comment: @Avi I found my answer my self. No need of your service

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex such as: `(\w+[\s,]+){0,4}stopped([\s,]+\w+){0,6}` which roughly translates to match 4 words before **stopped** and 6 words after.